# How to Upgrade PHP 5.5.12 to 5.6.12 in WampServer

Tags: php, windows, wampserver

I am new to PHP. Can you please give me step-by-step procedure for updating PHP 5.5.12 to 5.6.12?

I tried to solve my problem from  https://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/ , but I am troubled with the 5th step.

Comment: Is not easier Download a wamp installer with that php versión ? ... I mean with xampp works like that

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to do some research, make an attempt, and then post any errors or problems you are having from there. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: Sorry for that I will edit it now!

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion CarlosDelgado , naomik

Comment: There is a new version of Wampserver, 3.0, that includes PHP 5.6. You can download it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the outside WAMP Server seems to have stalled in making new releases. I've had the same problem in wanting to upgrade. I moved to [Easy PHP](http://www.easyphp.org/), this allows you swap in different PHP engines via a simple configuration front end.